# Sharing an iCloud calendar to other people causes a redirect loop (CalDav - HTTP 301)

Tags: icloud, ical, caldav

A friend of mine shared an iCloud calendar obtaining a WebDav URL, similar to this one:

```
webcal://p55-caldav.icloud.com/published/2/verylong-token-token-token
```

For a couple of years, since 2020, it worked perfectly. **Problem**: now, this iCloud URL causes an error "**too many redirects**" in whatever calendar app (e.g. nextCloud, WebDav Sync Adapter, Evolution, Thunderbird, etc.).

To further understand the situation I tried with cURL (omissis token):

```
$ curl --verbose --location http://p55-caldav.icloud.com/published/2/verylong-token-token-token

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: AppleHttpServer/57b15408e9be
Date: Wed, 16 Mar 2022 09:23:06 GMT
Location: https://p55-caldav.icloud.com/published/2/verylong-token-token-token

...

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: AppleHttpServer/57b15408e9be
Date: Wed, 16 Mar 2022 09:23:06 GMT
Location: https://p55-caldav.icloud.com/published/2/verylong-token-token-token

...

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: AppleHttpServer/57b15408e9be
Date: Wed, 16 Mar 2022 09:23:06 GMT
Location: https://p55-caldav.icloud.com/published/2/verylong-token-token-token

...

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: AppleHttpServer/57b15408e9be
Date: Wed, 16 Mar 2022 09:23:07 GMT
Location: https://p55-caldav.icloud.com/published/2/verylong-token-token-token

...
```

Now we are inside a very long **redirect loop** and then it quits with the related error:

```
* Maximum (50) redirects followed
curl: (47) Maximum (50) redirects followed
```

What's the problem? How to fix this? Has this happened to you?

If it helps, this calendar is probably gigantic. But if it was giant it should give a timeout or an error 500 or whatever but not a redirect on that same page, causing even more iCloud overload. Is this a bug?

Thank you for your ideas!

---

Edited from comments:

I tried using https instead of http. Nothing better happened.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue by getting a new URL for the public calendar.  I had to disable the public calendar setting and re-enable it.

Comment: I tried creating a new calendar and it didn't work.  When using `curl` to test, I get "Moved permanently" in the HTML response.

Comment: One thing to look out for.  The first time I tried that fix, it gave me back the same URL.  Eventually I came back to try again but this time I disabled it and removed all of the shares.  Left it for a few hours and re-shared and re-enabled public.  At that point I got a new URL and things started working again.  Still working today.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `https` instead of `http`.  That allowed me to download the calendar via `curl`.